# Is it possible to get camera information in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, camera

I am trying to build a tool in out of geometry, the idea being, it targets a camera, then affects the contained geometry based on camera info.

Position, rotation, etc. isn't proving to hard to get, but I would like to get information like *Field of View*.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know at the time of writing both camera and light data are not available for manipulation in Geometry Nodes, and you can't read object data properties from objects directly.

You can however use drivers to link that information into a node tree.

Hover you mouse over the property you want to import into your node tree, right click and select *Copy as New Driver*. In your *Geometry Nodes* insert a *Value* node (or whichever type matches or original property), right-click over the value and use *Paste Driver*.

[image]

You can also paste the driver directly in any node property button, however using a centralized "input" node will make it easier to reuse the driver value in different places in the tree, and reduce the risk of accidental removal.